# Assignment operator for reciprical in Objective-C

Tags: variable-assignment, operator-keyword

In Objective-C, I was wondering if there was such a thing as an assignment operator for a reciprocal. For example if you wanted to add 10 to an integer you could use the following code:

```
x = x + 10;
```

But a simpler assignment operator would be:

```
x += 10;
```

To make the variable into a reciprocal, I use the following code:

```
x = 1 / x;
```

I was wondering if there was an assignment operator to create the reciprocal rather than having to include the variable again. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: We don't know which language you're talking about.

Comment: Sorry about that. It's for Objective-C. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think the following link can help you to learn about various operators in objective c.

[various operations in objective c](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Objective-C_Operators_and_Expressions)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. In some languages `\` is assigned to left side division, which would make a good candidate (x \= 1). However, objective c doesn't allow even operator overloading and also the backslash is reserved for other uses in c-family languages.

I see the only workaround in a macro or a function `void rec(double &x){ x=1/x; }`, if typing a variable twice makes a problem.